# find_elements_by_xpath does not work and returns an empty list

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape reddits and the code below works when the URL page = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/announcements/hot/'

However, when I just change the URL a bit, page='https://www.reddit.com/r/announcements/new/' does not work. I have tried changing the sleep() but doesn't work. I have confirmed that the scrolling is working fine in both cases. What is the problem?

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

page = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/announcements/new/'
scroll_n_times = 10
scrape_comments = False
erase_db_first = True

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "core/chromedriver.exe",options=options)


#page = page.lower()
driver.get(page)

xpath = "//a[@data-click-id='body']"

sleep_time = 0.5
if (scroll_n_times != 0):
    print(('Opening reddit and scrolling: takes approximately {0} seconds'
           ).format(sleep_time * scroll_n_times))
else:
    print('Opening reddit and scrolling.. done')

try:
    # When scroll_n_times = 0, loop stops
    while scroll_n_times:
        # Scrolls browser to the bottom of the page
        height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, " + str(height) + ");")
        time.sleep(sleep_time)
        scroll_n_times -= 1

    elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)
    # elements = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, xpath)
    print(elements)

    # Get the link from the href attribute
    links = [tag.get_attribute('href') for tag in elements]

finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: The obvious explanation is that the `/r/announcements/hot/` has those elements, but the `/r/announcements/new/` page does not.  Can you say why you _expected_ those elements to be found?

Comment: Thank you, but I saw from the source that xpath elements exists! For example, from /new/ page I see a line : <a data-click-id="body" class="undefined" href=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For not logged in user, DOM structure a bit different in you case

Here is correct selector:

```js
css = "shreddit-post[comment-count]"

... 

// after scroll

 elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, css)

links = [el.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[slot=full-post-link]")
.get_attribute('href') for el in elements]
```

Comment: I now get it and works well! Thank you