# using Python requests library to log into reddit

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape html data from reddit when I am logged in, as the information I need is included in the logged-in page, not in the webpage when I am logged out(from [find_elements_by_xpath does not work and returns an empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76843989/find-elements-by-xpath-does-not-work-and-returns-an-empty-list)).

I am using the following code to request login, assuming the login URL is https://www.reddit.com/login/.

```
import requests


username="myuser"
password="password"
payload = {
            'loginUsername': username,
            'loginPassword': password
        }

# Use 'with' to ensure the session context is closed after use.
s = requests.Session()
headers = {'user-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

s.headers = headers
#login_url = f"https://www.reddit.com/user/{username}"
#print(login_url)
p = s.post("https://www.reddit.com/login/", data=payload)
# print the html returned or something more intelligent to see if it's a successful login page.
print(p.text)
print(p.status_code)
```

However, the status code returned is 404 and I get the following for `p.text`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-CA">
    <head>
        <title>
            
                reddit.com: Not found
            
        </title>

        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" sizes="512x512" href="https://www.redditstatic.com/accountmanager/favicon/favicon-512x512.png">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="https://www.redditstatic.com/accountmanager/favicon/favicon-192x192.png">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="https://www.redditstatic.com/accountmanager/favicon/favicon-32x32.png">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="https://www.redditstatic.com/accountmanager/favicon/favicon-16x16.png">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="https://www.redditstatic.com/accountmanager/favicon/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
        <link rel="mask-icon" href="https://www.redditstatic.com/accountmanager/favicon/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
        
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover">
        <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff"/>
        <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="https://www.redditstatic.com/accountmanager/favicon/mstile-310x310.png"/>
        <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="https://www.redditstatic.com/accountmanager/favicon/mstile-310x150.png"/>
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
        
        

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.redditstatic.com/accountmanager/vendor.4edfac426c2c4357e34e.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.redditstatic.com/accountmanager/theme.02a88d7effc337a0c765.css">


    </head>
    <body>
        























  <div class="Container m-desktop">
    <div class="PageColumns">
        
          
          <div class="PageColumn PageColumn__left">
          
            
<div class="Art"></div>

          </div>
        
        <div class="PageColumn PageColumn__right">
          
<div class="ColumnContainer">
  <div class="SnooIcon"></div>
  <h1 class="Title">404&mdash;Not found</h1>
  <p>
    The page you are looking for does not exist.
  </p>
</div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>


        <script>
            //<![CDATA
                
                window.___r = {"config": {"tracker_endpoint": "https://events.reddit.com/v2", "tracker_key": "AccountManager3", "tracker_secret": "V2FpZ2FlMlZpZTJ3aWVyMWFpc2hhaGhvaHNoZWl3"}};
            //]]>
        </script>
        

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.redditstatic.com/accountmanager/vendor.33ac2d92b89a211b0483.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.redditstatic.com/accountmanager/theme.5333e8893b6d5b30d258.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.redditstatic.com/accountmanager/sentry.d25b8843def9b86b36ac.js"></script>


    </body>
</html>
```

I tried using login URL as `login_url = f"https://www.reddit.com/user/{username}"`, but it still does not work.
I tried using `https://www.reddit.com/login` without the slash at the end, and the status is 400 and there is no output for `p.text`.
I believe the username and password I put in is correct. Should the login URL be something different?

I noticed at `https://www.reddit.com/login`, the action is as follows:

`<form class="AnimatedForm" action="/login" method="post">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Gathering information

If you insepct the Network calls, you'll see that it request the following data to be passed into the request:

[image]

Or

```py
login_data = {
    "csrf_token" "<RANDOM_VALUE>"
    "otp": "",
    "password": "PASSWORD", password
    "dest": "https://www.reddit.com",
    "username": "USERNAME", username
}
```

The problem is, that the `csrf_token` is dynamic, and changes for every request. So, what do we do?

##### Finding the `csrf_token`

The `csrf_token` is available when sending a `GET` request to the page. So, you can use a library such as [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to extract the token.

##### Notes

I found that you need to set the `content-type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

##### Code example

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

LOGIN_URL = "https://www.reddit.com/login"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36",
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
}

login_data = {
    
    "otp": "",
    "password": "PASSWORD",  # Replace with your Reddit password
    "dest": "https://www.reddit.com",
    "username": "USERNAME",  # Replace with your Reddit username
}

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers.update(headers)

    # Get the CSRF token
    response = session.get(LOGIN_URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    csrf_token = soup.find("input", {"name": "csrf_token"})["value"]
    login_data["csrf_token"] = csrf_token

    # Perform login
    with session.post(LOGIN_URL, data=login_data) as response:
        print(response)
```

###### See also

- [Get CSRF token using python requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51351443/get-csrf-token-using-python-requests)